# Is there a Perl implementation of Factor Graphs sum-product scheduling?

Tags: perl, algorithm

Are there good example codes of implementations of factor graph sum-product scheduling?  I am new to the concept, and would like to see how it gets implemented.

Comment: There are quite a few Graph related modules on CPAN (e.g. http://search.cpan.org/dist/Graph/ ) but I am not sure I know what *factor graph sum-product scheduling* is. Can you add a link to some description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [these lecture notes](http://www.stanford.edu/~montanar/TEACHING/Stat375/lecture-notes/lecture-1.pdf), *a factor graph is a bipartite graph*. I do not think there is an implementation of the *Sum-product scheduling* algorithm on CPAN, but [one of these modules](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=bipartite&mode=module) can provide a starting point.

Specifically, [Graph::Maker::Bipartite](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Graph::Maker::Bipartite) can facilitate the construction of the graph and you can then use [Graph](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Graph/) to traverse through nodes and iterate if you have a complete specification of the algorithm (which [this other set of lecture notes](http://ocw.mit.edu/NR/rdonlyres/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-451Spring-2005/E3F90835-0CA5-4F5A-8277-678CD418774C/0/chap12.pdf) seems to provide.